# Invisible character rendered between Twig includes

Tags: html, symfony, twig, byte-order-mark

I have a weird issue with a Twig `include` that's rendering some invisible character on my HTML. I've tried googling it in a thousand different ways, but couldn't find anyone with a similar issue. In fact, I'm not even sure if it's related to Twig or Symfony or what, so I'm not sure what I need to look for. I'll try m

At two different points in one of my views, I use a `for` loop to render each `li` by `include`ing a separate twig file, each time with a different set of arguments. The two loops are:

```html
<ul class="search-results">
    {% for entity in entities %}
        {% include 'SomeBundle:Users:renderUserResults.html.twig' with {'entity':entity, 'callType':0} %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and

```html
<ul class="search-results">
    {% for entity in entities %}
        {% include 'SomeBundle:Users:renderUserResults.html.twig' with {'entity':entity, 'time_search':time_search, 'time_meeting_search':time_meeting_search} %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The apparently relevant content of `renderUserResults.html.twig` is just:

```html
{% set role = common.roleClass(entity.type)|trim %}
<li class="{{ role }}">
    // a bunch of html
</li>
```

---

However, the generated code has a weird difference between both cases. In the first one, all the `li` elements are generated just fine, one after another, with just some spaces between them that are ignored by the browser. But in the second one, the Chrome Web Inspector shows some non-collapsing space **before** every `li`, like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/WsmI6g9]

And when right-clicking on one of those spaces and selecting "Edit as HTML", **this red dot appears**:

[image: http://imgur.com/p6xZ5lj]

That space is preventing the top and bottom margins of each `li` from collapsing (`li`s are rendered as a column of boxes), and therefore creating additional space which I don't want. I can't show a screenshot of the rendered list, so I hope I provided enough information.

---

So the bottom line is, I need to get rid of those red dots, but I have no idea why or where they are being created. As you can see, the only difference between the two cases is the set of parameters passed with the include, but I fail to see how that can cause a strange character to appear. I already tried using `{% spaceless %}` tags everywhere, and also manually deleting all spaces and line breaks in the twig files, but none of them worked. Manually deleting the red dots in the web inspector makes all the spaces between html tags to collapse again, but of course that's not an option.

Comment: What format are the twig files saved? UTF-8 or ANSII or something else?

Comment: I guess they are in UTF-8, though I'm not 100% sure about that (this is part of a big Symfony project, and I'm pretty new to Symfony). The base template, which this one extends, has a <meta charset="UTF-8"/> tag at the top, so I guess all the views in the project are in that format.

Comment: Do you have this issue just in Chrome or in any other browsers, too?

Comment: Yes, same with Firefox and Safari. I can't test with IE now. **Edit:** Just had another look and the red dots don't appear in neither Firefox nor Safari web inspectors, but the extra space is still there.

Comment: It's really weird, base on the images the weird character is after each *li* and not between `<li>` and `</li>`. So try to remove any spaces before those li and also in your for loop and see if it works

Comment: I noticed that, just before the first image link I said that the character is _before_ each `li`. The code in the third block I posted is at the very top of the file, so my try was removing the newline between the `{% set %}` and the `<li>`, but didn't work. May it has something to do with the parameters passed with the include? Sounds strange, but it's the only difference between the two pieces of code.

Comment: Can you verify that the files are in utf8 and without the BOM character? That may end up showing these symptoms.

Comment: Wow, that was it! After learning what the BOM character is (never heard of it before), I just saved the file with _UTF-8 without BOM_ encoding, and it worked (and it makes sense, since there's different people using different text editors for the project). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are symptoms that your file contains an utf8 [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It renders as an invisible character and can easily break php code, it is recommended you always save utf8 files without the BOM - all recent editors support this.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I saved the file with the _UTF-8 without BOM_ enconding and it solved the issue. Thank you!