# Twitter bootstrap generated empty space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, byte-order-mark

For some reason on just one of my pages I get an empty space that I believe is generated by the bootstrap's library.

I am including the page into a section `<section class="container col-md-8">` from another page, and the empty line shows up at the start of the section. On the F12 inspector it is seen as "      " and when I select to edit it as HTML, a small red dot appears. What might be the reason for it ? And it is generated only on this page, every other included page in the section is fine.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: show us the HTML it generated and a screen shot if possible

Comment: Your file is encoded in `UTF-8 with BOM`, change the encoding to `UTF-8 without BOM`.

Comment: I apologize for my unawareness! Holt, you were absolutely right. That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @Holt was provided in a comment *(posting as an answer so you can accept it to close the question!)*

> Your file is encoded in `UTF-8 with BOM`, change the encoding to `UTF-8 without BOM`

So it relates to the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) rendering in Chrome, and is a similar issue to:

[Invisible character rendered between Twig includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444802/invisible-character-rendered-between-twig-includes)

Chrome apparently shows those dots also in cases like [zero-width-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) characters, such as [in the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FFEsE/)